# Converting string to double returns with the full value, instead of the fraction C#

Tags: c#, macos, formatting

I am using Visual Studio on MAC (2021) and when I try to convert to double from a string, for example 0,3 it returns with 3.
The problem is the Macbook formatting, because it does not recognize ',' as the separator for fractions, instead it uses '.'
How do I change it to ',' or make MAC accept both?

```
string number = "0.3";
double fraction = double.Parse(number);
//this returns 0.3
```

```
string number = "0,3";
double fraction = double.Parse(number);
//this returns 3 -> expected to be 0.3 aswell
```

Comment: your expectation is wrong. a locale usually only has _one_ decimal separator. and it's not a mac-thing, it's a language-thing. also: what's stopping you from just using `string.Replace()`?

Comment: If the locale is, for instance, en-US then it will assume that a dot is a decimal separator and a comma is a group separator. If the locale is, for instance, fr-FR, it will assume the opposite. The OS will be irrelevant. You need to put some thought into where your data is coming from. If it's coming from a file that will always use the same culture formatting then hard-code that formatting. If it's coming from user input via the GUI then you should assume the culture formatting for the local machine, unless your app has made it clear to the user that it will be assuming a specific culture.

Comment: I am teaching in a middle-school, so I have to grade a lot of programming projects, and I don't really want to edit the students code just for running on my laptop :)
On windows it accepts ',' as fraction separator, on mac it is not, can I change the locale settings from '.' to ','?

Comment: Ohh I see, is there a way to change locale from en-US (it's probably that) to hu-HU? I hope that does not mess with the language of the system. @jmcilhinney

Comment: It's just a google away if you know what to look for: https://www.howtogeek.com/261330/how-to-change-your-macs-language-and-region-settings/

Comment: @David0425 .NET uses the user's locale settings. If your program runs in Hungary, it will use Hungarian settings. If, like many developers, you change your machine's locale to en-US because you don't like localized UIs, it will use those settings. A "slight" problem with MacOS is there are *multiple* ways you can (and need) to specify the locale - different LC_ settings for the shell, different for the machine

Comment: @David0425 web apps can autodetect the end user's locale (from the browser's preferred language settings) and change the active locale accordingly. This may or may not be desirable. It's also possible to use a specific locale for a request or user.

Comment: @David0425 you can try opening a shell and setting `LC_ALL` to `hu-HU.utf8` to test the programs. If that works, you could create a custom shell profile just for testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `double.Parse` which decimal separator you want to use:

```
double fraction = double.Parse(number); // uses the "current culture"    
double fraction = double.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // assumes "." as the decimal separator
double fraction = double.Parse(number, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")); // assumes "," as the decimal separator
```

However, for your use case, it might be easier to just set the current culture at the start of the program:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-HU");
```

> I am teaching in a middle-school, so I have to grade a lot of programming projects, and I don't really want to edit the students code just for running on my laptop

If your students' code assumes that `double.Parse(number)` always uses a specific decimal separator, your students' code contains a so-called **localization bug**. If it fits into your syllabus, this could be a great learning opportunity to teach them about localization issues!

Comment: _"This would be a great learning opportunity to teach them about localization issues!"_ +1 - and maybe a good opportunity to get onesself up to date with those :D

Comment: _" I don't really want to edit the students code just for running on my laptop"_ - which I wouldn't do anyway. **I'd set up a VM for that**. 1. You can reset it if need to. 2. Kids can only break the VM if they are really malicious ... ;) 3. You can set the locale / region and still have your preferred one in your "normal" environment.

Comment: Obligatory reference to the [Wikipedia Decimal separator article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) and the chart that shows that if it wasn't for China, most of the world would not be using `.` as a decimal  separator. It may be a good idea to include the map in the answer. Pacific uses `.`, rest of the world uses `,`. And South Africa .... oh my.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think anyone that once had to parse monetary amounts feels the pain ... ;)

Comment: Regarding the VM, on a Mac (or WSL) one could try setting a shell's `LC_ALL` to eg `hu-HU.utf8`. This wouldn't affect any other session.